# Open and Close Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, show

I've been trying to find help on creating this open div and closing div system.

It seems kind of simple, here's an example: http://codepen.io/sripavani/pen/WpQyYJ

What I am seeking is for the Register div to open when i click the signup a tag, which is located above the register div form. And so goes for the other way around, if they click on login the Register box closes and the login box opens.

I've set the Login div to be shown on startup and the Register box to be hidden.

```
<section class="secright">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="registerbutton">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a class="loginbutton1">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="register">
        <input class="input1" type="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
        <input class="input2" type="lastname" Placeholder="Lastname">
        <input class="input1" type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input class="input2" type="password" Placeholder="Password">
        <input class="input2" type="password" Placeholder="Repeat Password">
    </div>
    <div id="login">
        <input class="input1" type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input class="input2" type="password" Placeholder="Password">
        <button class="loginbutton2">Login</button>
        <div class="checkboxlogin">
            <input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
            <p>bla blaa blaaa</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's my HTML which is allready styled to my needs. Just need the above a tags to work so the user can register or login.

I'm hoping on some advice for Javascript or just a simple method on CSS. it doesn't need to have any fancy effect or anything. Do keep in mind, i don't know anything about javascript yet. Im well familier with HTML and CSS.

Comment: what is the class or id of the anchor tag for the signup element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `data-panel` attr to the links that represents the ID of the section/panel to show. Give the panels a consistent class, hide them by default, and add an `.active` class to denote which one should be shown. Then in jQuery, add the `.active` class  to the panel depending on which link you clicked.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button'),
    panels = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
    var target = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-panel'));
    for (var j = 0; j < panels.length; j++) {
      panels[j].classList.remove('active');
    }
    target.classList.add('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.panel:not(.active) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<section class="secright">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="registerbutton button" data-panel="register">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a class="loginbutton1 button" data-panel="login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="register" class="panel active">
        <input class="input1" type="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
        <input class="input2" type="lastname" Placeholder="Lastname">
        <input class="input1" type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input class="input2" type="password" Placeholder="Password">
        <input class="input2" type="password" Placeholder="Repeat Password">
    </div>
    <div id="login" class="panel">
        <input class="input1" type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input class="input2" type="password" Placeholder="Password">
        <button class="loginbutton2">Login</button>
        <div class="checkboxlogin">
            <input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
            <p>bla blaa blaaa</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Well, removed the display: none and display: block from my stylesheet and so far the script is working, it shows my login div on startup and hides the register div. Only thing is, nothing happens when i press the a tags ?

Comment: @Chris sorry, I thought you tagged the post with jquery but you didn't. re-wrote that jquery in vanilla javascript and updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Michael, i got it working with the jQuery just fine. It seems that i wasn't paying attention to the bottom of my HTML, i had an old jQuery which prevented the code from working.